# How can I determine the size of a trained model from TensorFlow Object Detection API v2?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I would like to know how or where I can find the size of a trained model from TensorFlow Object Detection API v2. I am not sure, but I am thinking that it could be the checkpoint data file with the larger file size (ckpt-35.data-00000-of-00001) as shown in this image:

[image]

Am I correct or wrong? If I am wrong, may I ask how I can determine the correct file size of the model?

Thank you.

Comment: why isn't this ok for you? maybe `sys.getsizeof()`?